# Get values from TEXTAREA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<textarea name="test" id="text">
    text
 area
    one one
  two

    break above
last
</textarea>  

<span id="getvalues">get values</span>  

$("#getvalues").click(function(){

})
```

How can i get all values from this textarea from each line to javascript array?
This should:

- ignore whitespace - trim
- ignore white break

Next i would like make:

```
$.each(textareavalues, function(index, value) { 
  console.log('@' + value + '@'); 
});
```

This should show me:

```
@text@
@area@
@one one@
@two@
@break above@
@last@
```

LIVE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/BW8Z2/1/

Comment: Your question reads like a homework assignment.

Comment: No, i have too many age for homework :P

Comment: My point was that it's an assignment.  It's like your directing the community to write your code for you.  That's not the proper way to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Adam Carter - I agree with you, but I answered anyway just for my own fun. (Yet although I met the exact "assignment" and produced an array that would work in the `$.each()` statement shown in the question still another answer that didn't do that was chosen...)

Comment: @nnnnnn If the questioner were informed enough to select the correct answer, he wouldn't need to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#getvalues").click(function(){
    var $textareavalues = $("#text").val();
    var x = $textareavalues.split('\n');
    $.each(x, function(index, value) {
      var text = $.trim(value);
      if(text !== "")
          console.log('@' + text + '@');
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't say `x[index]`, say `value` (that's what that second parameter of `$.each()` is for).

Comment: Are there any potential problems not using the supplied args and instead accessing the object directly?

Comment: I don't think there are any problems (theoretically it won't perform quite as well but I doubt you could tell). But why even bother using `$.each()` rather than a conventional `for` statement if you're not going to use those arguments?

Comment: I agree. A simple for loop would be more appropriate. Also, your answer is better so, +1

Answer (score 4):

When you say "ignore white space - trim", you mean "ignore leading and trailing white space on a line, but keep internal white space"? And "ignore white break" means "ignore lines with just white space"?

Something like this:

```
$("#getvalues").click(function(){
    var lines = $("#text").val()
                          .replace(/\n\s*\n/g,"\n")
                          .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,"")
                          .split(/\n/);

    $.each(lines, function(i, val) {
        console.log("@" + val + "@");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started:

```
var textareavalues = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
```

you can find how to trim strings and how to exclude empty items in an array in JavaScript from other questions on StackOverflow.